# Samsung Watch Sport Type Animations Source

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation, adobe, lottie

I'm just curious if someone knows whether the little sport type animations of the Samsung Watches are accessible or found anywhere. Can one reuse those?
I'm referencing the following, for example:

[image]

or

[image]

If it can't be found or is not accessible to the public, how may one rebuild similar animations in order to implement those in e.g. React Native applications?

Is Lottie a good solution with Adobe Illustrator + Adobe AfterEffects?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can implement this animation with Reanimated (maybe skia additions).